# reordering elements by css

Tags: html, css

I want to reorder the elements on my page using css but i couldn't find a way 
i tried all solutions I found here but no one work 
my html code is generated by WordPress that why i can't change the html code and I want to be for all the posts but I didn`t find a way to do it

```html
<article id="post-2433" class="et_pb_post clearfix post-2433 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-microsoft category-trucs-et-astuces">
   <div class="et_pb_image_container"> 
    <a href="http://cismdomain.com/les-5-astuces-sur-microsoft-edge/" class="entry-featured-image-url">
     <img src="http://cismdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Logo-Edge-400x250.png" alt="Les 5 astuces sur Microsoft Edge" height="250" width="400">
    </a>
   </div>
   <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://cismdomain.com/les-5-astuces-sur-microsoft-edge/">Les 5 astuces sur Microsoft Edge</a></h2>
   <p class="post-meta">
    <span class="published">Mar, 2017</span>
    |  
    <a href="http://cismdomain.com/category/microsoft/" rel="category tag">Microsoft</a>,
    <a href="http://cismdomain.com/category/trucs-et-astuces/" rel="category tag">Trucs et astuces</a>
   </p>
   <div class="post-content">
    <p>
     Microsoft Edge ce n’est pas juste un navigateur Web de recherche, mais aussi un outil complet que vous permet de créer des listes de lectures et écriture.
    </p>
    <a href="http://cismdomain.com/les-5-astuces-sur-microsoft-edge/" class="more-link">read more</a>
   </div>   
</article>
```

I want to make to show  without using jquery, I can use javascript

```html
1- <h2 class="entry-title">
2- <p class="post-meta">
3- <div class="et_pb_image_container">
4- <div class="post-content">
```

Comment: I dont have time to answer but if you use Javascripts [insertBefore()](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-952280727) function then you can add a dom above another in the html. After that you can do the same thing to move the other one and then delete the originals

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` with the `order` property on the children.

```css
article.post {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.entry-title, .post-meta {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<article id="post-2433" class="et_pb_post clearfix post-2433 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-microsoft category-trucs-et-astuces">
  <div class="et_pb_image_container">
    <a href="http://cismdomain.com/les-5-astuces-sur-microsoft-edge/" class="entry-featured-image-url">
      <img src="http://cismdomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Logo-Edge-400x250.png" alt="Les 5 astuces sur Microsoft Edge" height="250" width="400">
    </a>
  </div>
  <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="http://cismdomain.com/les-5-astuces-sur-microsoft-edge/">Les 5 astuces sur Microsoft Edge</a></h2>
  <p class="post-meta">
    <span class="published">Mar, 2017</span> |
    <a href="http://cismdomain.com/category/microsoft/" rel="category tag">Microsoft</a>,
    <a href="http://cismdomain.com/category/trucs-et-astuces/" rel="category tag">Trucs et astuces</a>
  </p>
  <div class="post-content">
    <p>
      Microsoft Edge ce n’est pas juste un navigateur Web de recherche, mais aussi un outil complet que vous permet de créer des listes de lectures et écriture.
    </p>
    <a href="http://cismdomain.com/les-5-astuces-sur-microsoft-edge/" class="more-link">read more</a>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex-box

```
#post-2433{
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.et_pb_image_container{
  order: 3;
}
.entry-title{
  order: 1;
}
.post-content{
  order: 4;
}
.post-meta{
 order: 2;
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? `flex-wrap` is unnecessary and this puts them in a row, not a column.